# Deploy ROR to heroku fails due to sqlite3 fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I've try the method from others post, but still cannot solve it.
I push my file to heroku but it have some error to the sqlite3.
After I install it, it still didn't work.
Below is my code

```
Counting objects: 82, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (70/70), done.
Writing objects: 100% (82/82), 3.00 MiB | 238 KiB/s, done.
Total 82 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Removing .DS_Store files
-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.2
   Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin --deployment
   Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
   Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
   Installing rake (10.0.4)
   Installing i18n (0.6.4)
   Installing multi_json (1.7.3)
   Installing activesupport (3.2.11)
   Installing builder (3.0.4)
   Installing activemodel (3.2.11)
   Installing erubis (2.7.0)
   Installing journey (1.0.4)
   Installing rack (1.4.5)
   Installing rack-cache (1.2)
   Installing rack-test (0.6.2)
   Installing hike (1.2.2)
   Installing tilt (1.4.1)
   Installing sprockets (2.2.2)
   Installing actionpack (3.2.11)
   Installing mime-types (1.23)
   Installing polyglot (0.3.3)
   Installing treetop (1.4.12)
   Installing mail (2.4.4)
   Installing actionmailer (3.2.11)
   Installing arel (3.0.2)
   Installing tzinfo (0.3.37)
   Installing activerecord (3.2.11)
   Installing activeresource (3.2.11)
   Installing coffee-script-source (1.6.2)
   Installing execjs (1.4.0)
   Installing coffee-script (2.2.0)
   Installing rack-ssl (1.3.3)
   Installing json (1.8.0)
   Installing rdoc (3.12.2)
   Installing thor (0.18.1)
   Installing railties (3.2.11)
   Installing coffee-rails (3.2.2)
   Installing jquery-rails (2.2.1)
   Using bundler (1.3.2)
   Installing rails (3.2.11)
   Installing sass (3.2.9)
   Installing sass-rails (3.2.6)
   Installing sqlite3 (1.3.7)
   Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
   /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
   checking for sqlite3.h... no
   sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal'
   or 'yum install sqlite-devel' and check your shared library search path (the
   location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
   *** extconf.rb failed ***
   Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
   necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
   details.  You may need configuration options.
   Provided configuration options:
   --with-opt-dir
   --without-opt-dir
   --with-opt-include
   --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
   --with-opt-lib
   --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
   --with-make-prog
   --without-make-prog
   --srcdir=.
   --curdir
   --ruby=/usr/local/bin/ruby
   --with-sqlite3-dir
   --without-sqlite3-dir
   --with-sqlite3-include
   --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
   --with-sqlite3-lib
   --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
   --enable-local
   --disable-local
   Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_2ghtqnawaxqqm/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7 for inspection.
   Results logged to /tmp/build_2ghtqnawaxqqm/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
   An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.7), and Bundler cannot continue.
   Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.7'` succeeds before bundling.
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app

To git@heroku.com:peaceful-reef-2102.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
```

And this is my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.11'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
```

I don't know what happen, please help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku doesn't support sqlite, you need to add pg gem (postgres) and remove sqlite gem